# How to pull changes to a branch into a testing server using git

Tags: git

I'm working on an application and have developed some new features. I'm now ready for these to be tested by my client on a test server for QA.

The new features were developed on a branch called 'Dev'. I've gone into my testing server and want to pull in this new branch so I've done...

```
git clone git@github.com:username/myrepo.git -b Dev
```

When I run this it just clones my master repo. How do I just clone the Dev branch?

Also how do I then pull in any changes I make to Dev on the testing server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see what I was doing, I just needed to reorder things...

```
git clone -b Dev git@github.com:username/myrepo.git
```

And then using...

```
git pull
```

Works just fine.